# 1 SSD windows, 1 SSD ext4, 1 NTFS Data mutual Drive?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I am trying to use a mutual Data hard drive (NTFS) to run my files between both windows and linux.

I am new to linux and having trouble with identifying the 3rd HD, which is NTFS.

On the sidebar, the GUI shows the drive I am looking to mount and eventually set up a write ability to, called DATA

I tried:

```
sudo su
fdisk -l
```

Only one result comes up: /dev/sdc1

This surprised me, so I tried this website's instructions
https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200288606-Mounting-NTFS-Drives-on-Linux

I was surprised, as when I followed this to the blkid command, I did not receive a list of UUIDs that were 32 characters, as I was expecting. It returned a 16 character sequence.

```
root@hoss:/# blkid|grep -i ntfs|sed 's/.*UUID="//g'|cut -d"\"" -f1|awk '{print "UUID="$!" /media/ntfsdrive ntfs-3g permissions,auto 0 0"}'
UUID=0C86BA8986BA72B6
UUID=5A58C0EC58C0C7C9
UUID=F050CABE50CA8B34
```

I then did:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

and found the various drives, all of them I remember setting up. I next tried querying each /dev/sd* to find which drive was the NTFS Data hard drive, which it turns out was sdc1, but again returned the same 16 code UUID:

```
jamie@hoss:/dev$ blkid /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Data" UUID="F050CABE50CA8B34" TYPE="ntfs"
```

I then tried a basic read mounting of NTFS as found on documentation here (http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Dapper#Windows)

and received this

```
root@hoss:/# sudo mount /dev/hdc1 /media/DATA/ -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume '/dev/hdc1': No such file or directory

ntfs-3g 2013.1.13AR.1 external FUSE 29 - Third Generation NTFS Driver
        Configuration type 7, XATTRS are on, POSIX ACLS are on

Copyright (C) 2005-2007 Yura Pakhuchiy
Copyright (C) 2006-2009 Szabolcs Szakacsits
Copyright (C) 2007-2012 Jean-Pierre Andre
Copyright (C) 2009 Erik Larsson

Usage:    ntfs-3g [-o option[,...]] <device|image_file> <mount_point>

Options:  ro (read-only mount), windows_names, uid=, gid=,
          umask=, fmask=, dmask=, streams_interface=.
          Please see the details in the manual (type: man ntfs-3g).

Example: ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows

News, support and information:  http://tuxera.com
```

So I am now stuck, and my question is, where would you go from here, to try and have a mutual Hard Drive in NTFS between linux and windows? Sorry for the long post, and thanks for taking the time to read this.

**EDIT 1**

Thanks to Muru (in the comments) I noticed that I entered in a spelling mistake (trying to mount hdc, not sdc)

I went back and repeated the steps with the correct spelling, this is what it said:

```
jamie@hoss:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/DATA/ -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I am not looking for a 'read only', I also want to be able to write, but I am not sure what metadata is kept in windows cache. Is it possible the bootloader that enables me to choose between windows and linux on boot is causing this, or does recognize this and know a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're doing. NTFS drives have 16-character UUIDs, that's normal. You say `/dev/sdc1` has the NTFS partition, yet the mount command is for `/dev/hdc1`. Where did `hdc1` come from?

Comment: Hi Muru, ah I didn't realise 16-character UUIDs were the norm for NTFS, well that is reassuring. /dev/hdc1 is the third hard drive in the computer that I am trying to mutually read + write to from both windows and ubuntu. Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't properly remove the drive from windows. Boot back into windows and safely remove it. Let it finish writing all data then try in Ubuntu again

Comment: Seconded. The only way to fix an unclean NTFS filesystem is to use Windows. :( (Also NTFS and FAT32 UUIDs are not the same as ext4/other linux FS UUIDS. You can use them, but don't rely on them.)

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo parted -l
```

This will list drives, partition tables, partitions, and filesystems.

Comment: If this answers the question that was asked here, I recommend expanding this (by editing) to explain how.